# What is a 20OE Wiper Blade?

Tags: vw, windshield-wipers

I know that A means driver side and B means passenger side. But I saw a product online that said 20OE. What is the OE?

Background: I'm looking for replacement wiper blades for a '99 Volkswagen Beetle Bug. Looking online, they say to use 21 inch wiper blades. However, when I went on Amazon and selected a certain product (Bosch), Amazon suggested it didn't fit my car. When I used their search page, I saw a bunch of 21 inch blades, and Bosch's was marked 20OE. What's that?

Answer (score 1):

"A" is for the driver side and for some vehicles the passenger side.
"B" is for vehicles that require a different wiper on the passenger side.
"OE" means Original Equipment Fitment, and has to do with the type of arm connectors the blade has.  The OE blades are not side specific.

Answer (score 0):

Both Amazon's system and the O'Reilly parts store system said the 21 inches would not fit. But both systems said the other brands' 21 inches would fit. At the store clerk's suggestion, I just tried the Bosch 21 inches A and B.

They work great. Way better than the other brands that fit.

I don't know why Amazon recommended 20OE for my car. The 21s fit perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The people at AutoZone gave two reasons. The first was the curve of the windshield. If the windshield is really rounded at the ends, the wiper is shaped to account for it (A on the left and B on the right). The OE is made for a flatter windshield so they're interchangeable.

The other was the j-hook mount. On some cars the j-hook doesn't fit quite right, so the wiper might just come loose and fly off while you're driving along. The OE accounts for that.